# Update "Introducing Programmers" blog to reflect site scope change

Tags: support, status-completed, site-definition, bad-questions, low-quality-posts

In the [Introducing programmers.stackexchange.com](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/12/introducing-programmers-stackexchange-com/) blog post, Jeff announces our site with great fanfare.  And while I'm all for promoting our site, there are a few problems with that post that I think are creating recurring issues for us.

First off, there's a link to the FAQ which now redirects to our /tour page.  It would be a lot more helpful if that redirected to our /help/on-topic page instead.  The tour is a nice intro, but doesn't as clearly explain to a new visitor what's on-topic or not.

The other major challenge in that blog post is this:

> Although I fully supported this site when it was just a baby Area 51 site proposal, we’ve endured a lot of angst over it — mainly because **it veered so heavily into the realm of the subjective**. It forced us to think deeply about what makes a useful subjective question, which we formalized into a set of 6 guidelines in Good Subjective, Bad Subjective. Constructive subjective questions …
>   ...  [*edited for clarity*]
>   Ultimately, with a little extra discipline and moderation, I think the site turned out great. So, go forth and ask your **subjective whiteboard questions** on programmers.stackexchange.com! Just make sure they’re professional and constructive, please.

And that's where I cried a little bit when I recently re-read that post.

Given the site's dramatic shift in focus from when it originally started, I don't feel that the blog post announces our site in a constructive way.  In fact, [there's anecdotal evidence](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/21?m=19899888#19899888) that it's actively misleading new users.

---

Can one of these two things be done, please?

- <strike>Update the blog post to redirect to /help/on-topic ***and*** provide a notice indicating that the site scope has changed since that blog post was made.</strike>
- Just make that blog post go away forever.

---

After digging through the comments on that post, I think we should just make that particular post go away forever.

In particular, [this comment](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/12/introducing-programmers-stackexchange-com/#comment-55417) is what should be the final nail in the coffin:

> The last thing either site needs is people asking perfectly good programming questions on a site explicitly created for non-programming questions.
>   But if you do get the urge to ask (or answer…) a question that ISN’T strictly programming-related, now you have a place to do so.

Granted, no one reads comment threads on old blog posts but that comment is horrifically misleading at this point in time.

Comment: I bet the [comment](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/12/introducing-programmers-stackexchange-com/#comment-55417) meant that [folks they throw over the cliff at Stack Overflow](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/7020/31260) shouldn't be asking etc. :) Quite a pity that they do... guess they haven't read this comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've updated the article to either call out or paper over the areas that had become somewhat dated.

That said, I stand by that comment. Folks really shouldn't be asking programming questions here.