# About that "Good Subjective Bad Subjective" blog post and Programmers

Tags: support, subjective, site-definition, bad-questions, low-quality-posts

In the continuing effort to clean up our image and the historical pathways that people find Programmers.SE (in the spirit of [Update "Introducing Programmers" blog to reflect site scope change](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7166/update-introducing-programmers-blog-to-reflect-site-scope-change) ) I would point to [Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/09/29/good-subjective-bad-subjective/).

This blog post features the text:

> But software and programming isn’t always a hard science, either. Once you get past the does this code compile or not questions, you’re dealing with issues of best practices, experiences, and behaviors. Perhaps because our communities have become so accustomed to getting quick, accurate, and timely answers, they feel that even a subjective Stack Overflow is better than the alternatives. So much so, that our fellow programmers created [a sister site specifically for their pent up subjective questions](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/). Take one heaping pile of subjective questions, bottle it up for over two years and… kablooey!
>
> [image: stats]
>   <sub>(source: [stackoverflow.com](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/wp-content/uploads/programmers-se.png))</sub>
>
> The [programmers.stackexchange.com](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) site exploded overnight, hosting some of the best (and worst) questions on the Stack Exchange network.

and then further down:

> You can expect to see these guidelines enforced on programmers.stackexchange.com over the next week or so, and made policy network-wide, wherever subjectivity is part of the site topic itself.

So, here's the question to consider. Would a person reading that understand what the scope of Programmers.SE as it is today is intended to be?

In particular, we are *not* a place for subjective discussions.

I would suggest putting in an "editor's note" to the effect that Programmers.SE is the place for *conceptual* questions of software design and architecture and while this does stray into the softer side of answers, it is certainly not the place for subjective discussions that the site was when it was 29 days old.

P.S.  Your links to "The chat room/forum problem (& an apology to @Technosailor)" are dead.  The new link is http://scobleizer.com/?p=5980

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yeah, ok, done.

> ***Editorial note (May 26, 2015):** It's instructive to look back now on the direction the Programmers community took after the enforcement of these standards began... Today it remains an excellent venue for conceptual questions on programming and software development, but has little patience for the sorts of overtly-subjective discussions (some might say "navel-gazing") that marked its early history. You can read more about the history of this site and these questions in [veteran moderator Yannis's writeup on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167516/how-can-i-encourage-stack-overflow-to-rein-in-the-subjective-vigilantes/200144#200144).*

Comment: Thank you very much.  There's one more broken link in "as Robert Scoble correctly pointed out" at the very end.

Comment: thanks; corrected that as well.